# How to display the desired elements from Google Maps API reverse geocoding?

Tags: javascript, reverse-geocoding

I want to display a specific result using the Google Maps API reverse geocoding. I'm pulling in what I want in the console, but I'm blanking on pulling it in the display.

In addition, I can't get the form field to populate with the data. It populates in the

tag, but doesn't go into the form

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Strawmr/pen/yLBXZVR

**JS**

```
   (function() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
            locElement = document.querySelector("#loc"),
            google_coords;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
            google_coords = new google.maps.LatLng(
                e.coords.latitude,
                e.coords.longitude // current address
            );
            geocoder.geocode({ latLng: google_coords }, 
        reverseGeocoderSuccess);
        });

        function reverseGeocoderSuccess(results, status) {
            var address;
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    var address_components = 
        results[0].address_components;
                    address = results[0].formatted_address;
                    locElement.innerHTML = address;

                    // print desired result to the console:
                    console.log(
                        address_components[3].short_name + ", " +address_components[5].short_name + " " + address_components[7].long_name + ", " + address_components[6].long_name
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    })();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <fieldset class="address">
        <legend>Address</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-md-3">
            Location
        </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="loc" name="Location" value="" autocomplete="address-level2">
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the result appear in the form input box you can replace

```
locElement.innerHTML = address;
```

with

```
document.getElementById("loc").value = address;
```

To display a Google Map with the location (which I think is what you're trying to do) you will have to create a Map object and give it a center of your address coordinates. Something like:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {
            lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), 
            lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
          },
            zoom: 8,
        });
```

For the above to work you will also need to add a div to your HTML with id of map:

```
<div id='map'></div>
```

You can then also add markers, pop-up boxes etc to the map object.

Comment: The first part worked great! For the second part, I'm not actually trying to display the map. Rather, I'm trying to get the address that displays in text to only display specific elements (the elements being called in the console.log line)

Comment: Can you not just use the same variables you log to the console e.g. `locale = address_components[3].short_name + ", " +address_components[5].short_name + " " + address_components[7].long_name + ", " + address_components[6].long_name`
and then assign locale to the value variable of the 'loc' element